# Practical context for a quadratic equation with negative discriminant.

Tags: complex-numbers, education

I'm looking for practical questions that lead to quadratic equations with negative discriminant.  The pupils involved are 16 years old and technically educated.

Abstract mathematic questions are quite easy to create, e.g. "We're looking for two numbers, whose sum is 5 and product 7", but I'd like 'real world' examples.

I imagine that electrical calculations could probably be used, but I'm afraid I'm not technically educated myself (alas).

**EDIT**

What I'm really looking for is an example where the question and the solutions to the equation are somehow 'connected' to the real world.

Answer (score 2):

They are too early in their mathematical careers to understand what a differential equation is, but you could explain that for instance, when there is a spring with a weight tied to the end, then there is a quadratic polynomial whose discriminant is negative/positive according as to whether the spring will oscillate or not when released.

Answer (score 0):

The historical context was that such equations appeared in the solution of cubic equations that were known to have real solutions and this led to the invention of complex numbers.

Comment: I'm aware of the historical context of complex numbers, but we're obliged to teach our pupils 'questions that involve solving quadratic equations with negative discriminant'.  If i have to do so, I'd rather look for real-life examples (perhaps only used as an example if they are too difficult), than limit myself to 'abstract mathematics' questions...

Answer (score 0):

You have 5 meters fence.  Is it possible to build a rectangular pen with that fence with area 7 square meters?

Comment: I see that, but I don't see a real-life application of the solutions of the quadratic equation this way.

Comment: Well, it just doesn't have a solution. As the discriminant is negative that the equation doesn't have a solution.  But that may *mean* something, anyway.  Consider the unit cycle given by $x^2+y^2=1$ and the straight line given by $x+y=2$.  Searching for common points yields to a quadratic with negative discriminant, thus  no solution.  But that *means* that the line and the circle don't have a common point.

Comment: OK, I understand that, but that's an important issue when you're studying quadratic equations, where you can find 0, 1 or 2 solutions and interpret that.  What I'm trying to find is a complex solution to a quadratic equation, that has meaning in real life.